# Smoothly changing padding of element sticked to the top while scrolling vertically the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I've managed to sort out the sticking header when page is scrolled vertically, however I'd like to smoothly change the padding of header depending on how much the page is scrolled. At the moment it's fixed one-shot change. 
What I want is to keep changing padding of header along with scrolling down the page, not straight jump to another padding value. Of course the header sticks on the top.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/5vhbv0dL/)

Here is the code

```
<div id="ontop">something</div>
<header>navigation</header>
<div id="wrapper"> 
1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>10<br/>
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
#ontop {width:100%; height:80px; background-color:yellow;}
header {width:100%; height:20px; background-color:lightgrey; padding:60px 0;}
#wrapper {background-color:lightblue; height:5000px;}
.navfixed {position: fixed; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width:100%; display:block; margin-bottom:120px; padding:10px 0;} 
.wrapperBelow{margin-top:42px;}
```

and here is the jsquery:

```
$(function () {
    var elem = $('header'),
        wrapperElem = $('#wrapper'),
        elemTop = elem.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        elem.toggleClass('navfixed', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
        wrapperElem.toggleClass('wrapperBelow', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
    }).scroll();
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add transition to your css styling of header

transition: padding 0.5s linear;

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agz9Ljkj/)

```js
$(function() {
  var elem = $('header'),
    wrapperElem = $('#wrapper'),
    elemTop = elem.offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    elem.toggleClass('navfixed', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
    wrapperElem.toggleClass('wrapperBelow', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
  }).scroll();
});
```

```css
#ontop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 60px 0;
  transition: padding 0.5s linear;
}
#wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 5000px;
}
.navfixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 120px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.wrapperBelow {
  margin-top: 42px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ontop">something</div>
<header>navigation</header>
<div id="wrapper">1
  <br/>2
  <br/>3
  <br/>4
  <br/>5
  <br/>6
  <br/>7
  <br/>8
  <br/>9
  <br/>10
  <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Diamond. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: is it working for all browsers and systems? including mobile?

Comment: Add this:

 -webkit-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
    transition: padding 0.5s linear;

**works for most modern browsers**

Comment: Dear @Diamond, could you please help me with one more thing? please take a look on this: http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/agz9Ljkj/2/ . How can I make the wrapper going smoothly up along with the header, instead of immediate change of margin-top? Cheers

Comment: @Piotr Ciszewski Add smooth scrolling to your page take a look at https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll